# Firefox with Pentadactyl inserts extra linebreak in Jupyter / Ipython Notebook on Return

Tags: firefox, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

**EDIT:** <s>I just noticed that the behaviour described below is only observed in Firefox. In Chrome, only one newline is inserted. Strange.</s> It turns out that this only happens when I use Firefox' Pentadactyl addon in Insert mode. When entering Pass-Through mode (`C-z`), only one linebreak is inserted. So this problem apparently has nothing to do with Jupyter.

In Jupyter and Ipython-Notebook, respectively, the standard behaviour when hitting return is to insert a new paragraph (which looks like `\n\n`). Is it somehow possible to instead have it insert just a linebreak, i.e. `<br/>`?

I am working with a lot of mathematical elements in my notebooks, which forces me to constantly hit `<Return><Backspace>` in order to get simple linebreaks. Otherwise, the Markdown interpreter doesn't properly parse the text. For example, when I want to have a simple `align` environment, the standard behaviour would result in something resembling the following:

```
\begin{align}

x &= y \\

  &= z

\end{align}
```

This would then be improperly interpreted. Hitting Backspace at the right places, the following *will* be interpreted corectly:

```
\begin{align}
x &= y \\
  &= z
\end{align}
```

Comment: Could [this](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/docs/source/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.ipynb) be a starting point?

Answer (score 0):

This problem has nothing to do with Jupyter / Ipython-Notebook. Instead, it seems to be a quirk of Pentadactyl (a Firefox addon). I have not yet figured out why this happens, but the fix is to not edit the notebook in `Insert` mode, but to use `Pass-Through`, accessible through `C-z`.

I will update this answer should I figure out how to make `Insert` mode work without adding spurious linebreaks.